# How many definitions of a list of 30 would I need to know so that I could answer at least 10 from any 18?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

While studying for my English exam, I noticed that the way the definitions portion of the final is set up posed an interesting problem. While I will study all the definitions, I thought trying to solve this might be fun and just got totally stuck.

Given a list of 30 possible terms, 18 of them will be on the final exam; the final exam requires that I choose and define 10 of them. What is the minimum number of the terms I need to know so that for any 18 chosen, I know at least 10 words.

So far, I have found $$\alpha ={30 \choose 18}\cdot{18 \choose 10}$$ where $\alpha = 3.7847705 \times 10^{12}$.

My best guess for how to continue would be to find a number $$\beta = {30 \choose 18}\cdot{18 \choose k}$$
with $k \gt 10$ such that $$\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \le C$$ for some $C$.

My problem is that the discrete math I've seen thus far hasn't really told me how to proceed with a question like this, if there is a method, as I learned mostly about identities.

Comment: Say you know $N$ of them.  That means there are $30-N$ you don't know.  In a worst case, all those $30-N$ are on the exam so you need  $30-N≤8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be answered simpler than that. The answer is that you need to learn $22$ words in order to guarantee knowing 10 in any selection of $18$.

We need to show that $22$ is sufficient and that anything less than $22$ won't always work.

To show that $22$ is sufficent, consider the worst case scenario: all $30 - 22 = 8$ words that you didn't study are part of the test. Then that means you know the remaining $10$ of those $18$ words, so you can pick those $10$ and all is well.

To show that anything less than $22$ isn't enough, consider this worst case scenario again. If you only learn $N$ terms, where $N < 22$, then the worst case scenario has $30 - N$ words you didn't study among the $18$ words, so $18- (30 - N) = N - 12$ words that you do know. You need $N - 12 \geq 10$, thus $N \geq 22$.

Comment: Much simpler than how I was going about trying to solve it. I just saw the $k \lt m \lt n$ formation and jumped right to that relation. Out of sheer curiosity, is there a way a problem like this can be solved using a method akin to the one I attempted, or was I way off base? A simple reference to a website on the matter would suffice, as I couldn't find any myself.

Comment: @AuditionMD My intuition is telling me no, since this solution basically just needed the pigeonhole principle / worst case scenario analysis and it would seem like anything with binomial coefficients and no other high-powered tools would use the same logic, just with more complicated language. However there could be a more complicated, high-powered method that works for this that I am not aware of.

Comment: That is fair, I completely neglected the pigeonhole principle because I saw it as a subset of a subset system. However, drawing out $18$ boxes and filling them sequentially with $30$ marks (representing words) leaves $11$ boxes with $2$ marks each for $22$ marks total. Is there some specific meaning behind this being $(10+1)*2$ or is it specific to this case?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario: the $30-18=12$ words not on the test are all ones that you know. In that case, you would need to know an additional $10$ from the remaining to be able to get a perfect score. This means you could get away with a minimum of $22$ words.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks, mate! Yeah, I don't know why either. I got the same answer as everyone else, and I don't think my reasoning was bad. Whatevs.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than $18-10=8$ words whose definitions you don't know, and they are all on the final, you're out of luck. If there are $8$ or fewer that you don't know, you're in the clear, even if every single unknown word shows up on the final! So, at most, you may neglect $8$ of the $30$ words, meaning you must know at least $30-8=22$ words.